# Chain of REST path in spring boot controller

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, jakarta-ee

I develope RESTful back-end app with spring boot. I find out how to use annotation in the class:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/users")
public class User{
    // rest of code!
}
```

But every user has orders and any orders has items! So I design rest API like this:

```
/users /users/{user_id}
/users/{user_id}/orders
/users/{user_id}/orders/{order_id}
/users/{user_id}/orders/{order_id}/items
/users/{user_id}/orders/{order_id}/items/{item_id}
/users/{user_id}/cart
```

Now, what is best practice or normal implementation for this design in spring boot? How can I handle APIs with Spring Boot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Continue and use the annotated method inside the class:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/users")
public class UserController {

    @GetMapping("/{user_id}")
    public User getUserById(@PathVariable("user_id") String userId) { }

    @GetMapping("/{user_id}/orders")
    public List<Order> getOrdersByUserId(@PathVariable("user_id") String userId) { }

     @GetMapping("/{user_id}/orders/{order_id}")
    public List<Order> getOrdersByIdAndUserId(@PathVariable("user_id") String userId, @PathVariable("order_id") String orderId) { }

    // ... and so on
}
```

- Don't forget the implementation inside the `{}` brackets.
- The example method `getOrdersByIdAndUserId` is mapped to the `GET` method of path `/users/{user_id}/orders/{order_id}` where `/users` is a common part defined as the class mapping and the rest with the method.
- I suggest you rename the class `User` to `UserController`, because the `User` is a suitable name for the returned entity.

Comment: a stupid question: can i use order controller for that? I known this not logical, they have separate business but my mind is involved.

Comment: No question is stupid. It depends if the `/users/{user_id}/orders/{order_id}` would return the same as `/orders/{order_id}` - whether the `order_id` is a number of the user's order or a number of all the orders. Generally, I don't recommend to call one controller from another.